# Difference between test_urls.py and test_views.py

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm currently learning how to write tests in Django:
I've used the approach to create an extra test folder which has test files for every "Django module".

```
tests/
    test_urls.py
    test_views.py
    test_models.py
    ...
```

My problem is that I don't know the exact different between the test_urls.py file and test_views.py

For example I have this test:

```
def test_login_url(self):
    path = reverse('login')
    response = self.client.get(path)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Should I place this test in the test_urls.py file or in test_views.py
The "login" url is in the urls.py file but the view that belongs to that url is in views.py

Which file should I choose? Are there any best practices for this?

Comment: You generally should avoid testing things provided by framework, or third parties generally speaking, so testing if urls are registered correctly is pointless. What you should test is behavior that you implement.

Comment: @gonczor what if my login views breaks because another developer changed the template name that does not exists. I wouldn't notice this without the test above. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have a custom template for login it's testable. You could check whether all rendered elements are displayed.

Comment: @gonczor Ah, I did not know that I can test if elements are displayed. That answers my question. I will remove test_urls.py because this are the only tests in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create test_urls.py at all. Anyway, you will assert response status code while testing views.

```
def test_get_users(self):
    for i in range(3):
        user = User(name='Test user {}'.format(i))
        user.save()
    path = reverse('users')
    response = self.client.get(path)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(len(response['users']), 3)
```